# Layers visibility- code error in Arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-10.3, layers, mapserver, nameerror

I try to turn of all the layers, using this code using ArcGIS 10.3.1:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = r"G:\desktop\gis"
for mxd in arcpy.ListFiles("*.mxd"):
    mapdoc = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument\
         (r"G:\desktop\gis\\" + mxd)
    for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapdoc):
        lyr.visible = False
    mapdoc.save()
del mxd
```

This code works great, but there are several maps with layers from this server: 
http://www4.emap.co.il/ArcGIS/rest/services

and it make some error:

```
NameError: The attribute 'visible' is not supported on this instance of Layer.
```

How can I overcome this error?

Comment: Use the supports method to check if the layer supports visibility Before trying to set it to False

Comment: i using ArcGIS version 10.3.1

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the "**supports**" method to identify if the "visible" property will work.

Try:

```
for lyr in arcpy.mapping.ListLayers(mapdoc):
    if lyr.supports("VISIBLE"):
        lyr.visible = False
```

See [link](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/analyze/arcpy-mapping/layer-class.htm) for more information.

Comment: It will throw exception anyway. The `else` part is redundant.

Comment: MacroZED, still i get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

I was encountering this same error with the ArcGIS Pro 'mp' module for Arcpy. I determined that the reason the 'visible' property was not editable was because the layers I was trying to control were inside of a group layer. When I placed them outside of the group layer, I was able to control the 'visible' property successfully. Hope this helps others having this issue.